# Running selenium test in Docker

Tags: python, selenium, docker

I wrote a selenium script that works works fine when I launch it using cmd.

I would like now to execute the script in a docker so that it can easily be launched from any machine in one click.

I wrote a Dockerfile using the base image `FROM selenium/standalone-chrome-debug`

I changed my script like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

But when I launch it, I have the following error :

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd11b9e3b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I'm new to docker and selenium so I may have forgot something.

Comment: did you puplish the port 4444 , in your docker run command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing local IP and local port number

http://127.0.0.1:4444   - your IP is local and local port

You need to identify your selenium hub docker `ip` and `port` on which hub running on same VM and update your below line:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response, I managed to make it work and indeed I was missing the selenium hub step